# Access a class instance inside a other class from xaml in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

My class looks like this:

```
public class testclass
{
    public List<otherClass> references { get { return _references; } }
}
```

My otherClass looks like this

```
public class otherClass
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

And now i try to access this "otherClass" inside a DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="templateCore" DataType="{x:Type vm:AdminInterfaceViewModel}" >
    <GroupBox DataContext="{Binding references }">
        ...
</DataTemplate>
```

this works fine, or i think at least, beaucse intellisense autocomplete it. But now  how can i get access to the name property of the "otherClass" ?

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to binding the List to a ItemsControl type,such as ListBox,DataGrid etc,and the ItemsControl will use the 'otherClass' instance in the List as the DataContext for each item in it.So you can find a 'mapping' there:

> ```
>  'List<otherClass>'--'ItemsControl'
>
>  'otherClass'--'Item'
> ```

.

I suppose that 'AdminInterfaceViewModel' is your DataContext,and 'references' is one property of it, so try this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="templateCore" DataType="{x:Type vm:AdminInterfaceViewModel}" >
    <GroupBox>
      <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding references}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TexBox Text="{Binding name}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      </ListBox>
    </GroupBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

**> Update:**

1.Suppose that you have a MainViewModel which contains a property named MyViewModel in type of 'AdminInterfaceViewModel '.

```
class MainViewModel
{
   public AdminInterfaceViewModel MyViewModel  {get; set;}
}
```

2.You have set the 'MainViewModel' as the DataContext of your Window,then you can use the property 'MyViewModel' in xaml.

```
 <Window>
   <Grid>
      <ContentControl Margin="20" Content="{Binding MyViewModel}">

      </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
 </Window>
```

3.Define the DataTemplate in your ResourceDictionary such as 'generic.xaml'.Remove the x:Key then the DataTemplate will automatically applied to every 'AdminInterfaceViewModel' type instance.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="templateCore" DataType="{x:Type vm:AdminInterfaceViewModel}" >
    <GroupBox>
      <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding references}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TexBox Text="{Binding name}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      </ListBox>
    </GroupBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

### > **Tips**:

**Check this link,it may solve your potential problems:[MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)**

Comment: Intellisense like it :) But how do u use the DataTemplate?

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateCore}"/>

?

Comment: @benba You mean how to use the ViewModel?There are several way.If you want to use the DataTemplate as a content in a ContentContro?Check the  update.

Comment: I don't get it to work. when i access one instance directly, it worked. It seems, I have to read more about DataTemplates...

Comment: @benba It does has some details that I didnt mentioned.Check the Link above in my update.It will tell the typical way to use the DataTemplate and MVVM.